# Как уменьшить высоту блока в два раза?

Tags: html, css

Допустим у нас есть div высотой 300px (но размер будет меняться), и нужно чтобы он стал max-height: 150px, а при @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) он был max-height: 100%;

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Или никак, или сложно и некроссбраузерно. И вообще, какое-то нелогичное поведие. Ну либо я неправильно понял описание.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что по медиа-запросу надо выставлять max-height в половину высоты содержимого div'а?

Comment: Да, нужно выставлять по содержимому

Comment: @AndreyWayne так что же мешает Вам прописать для `@media screen and (max-width: 1280px)` `max-height: 100%;` ?

Comment: вопрос не в этом